# Variable scope and the 'using' statement in .NET

Tags: .net, using

If a variable is at class level (ie, `private MyDataAccessClass _dataAccess;`, can it be used as part of a using statement within the methods of that class to dispose of it correctly?

Is it wise to use this method, or is it better to always declare a new variable with a `using` statement (ie, `using (MyDataAccessClass dataAccess = new MyDataAccessClass())` instead of `using (_dataAccess = new MyDataAccessClass())`)?

Comment: since the object will be disposed once it exits the using block, I see no benefit of having a variable/reference to the object after that. So `(using var x = ...` for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> You can instantiate the resource
>   object and then pass the variable to
>   the using statement, but this is not a
>   best practice. In this case, the
>   object remains in scope after control
>   leaves the using block even though it
>   will probably no longer have access to
>   its unmanaged resources. In other
>   words, it will no longer be fully
>   initialized. If you try to use the
>   object outside the using block, you
>   risk causing an exception to be
>   thrown. For this reason, it is
>   generally better to instantiate the
>   object in the using statement and
>   limit its scope to the using block.

So technically it'll work, in that it will compile and run and perform as designed.  But it's probably not a good idea and won't make for very intuitive code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it matters, but I would use a local variable instead of a class level variable simply because it reduces coupling with other class methods.

Answer (score 0):

When using "using" inside a method, only if the object is initialised inside the using statement will the object be disposed when the using block closes.
Since your object is defined outside of the using block, I don't believe it would automatically be disposed though it should be "closed" since there would still be a reference to it throughout the rest of the program